# "The given entity must not be null" error when calling refresh token api using oauth2

Tags: jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, spring-data, jhipster

I am using Jhipster with Oauth2 implementation and mongodb as a database. Jhipster has its own implementation of Tokenstore to manage access and refresh tokens.

I have set the token expiration time to 30 seconds just for testing and what I observe is that if I call refresh token api after 30 sec it returns error:

{
    "error": "server_error",
    "error_description": "The given entity must not be null!"
}

What might be the issue here? Is the refresh token also expired after 30 seconds?

Comment: As it's a server error, you should look at server logs for details

Answer (score 1):

Spring security will check if there is an existing access token that has been expired, then remove it and also remove the refresh token, if refresh token is still valid, tokenId will be kept, and create new record for refresh token.

You can see detail from the class `DefaultTokenServices#createAccessToken`

However if there are multiple access token have same refresh tokenId, only 1 invalid access token is removed, and the relevant refresh token would be removed as well. Later once you request to get new access token, there are still some expired access token, it will be removed, however the relevant refresh token has been removed already by last request, so you will get that exception because of null refresh token

See detail at class `MongoDBTokenStore#removeRefreshToken`

Suggestion fix here is that:
Update the code from the method `removeRefreshToken`

```
OAuth2AuthenticationRefreshToken refreshToken = oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.findByTokenId(token.getValue());
if (refreshToken != null) {
    oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository.delete(refreshToken);
}
```

I have created an issue here for jHipster team https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2924